# Access osgi bundle's lib jars

Tags: java, osgi

I'm developing an osgi bundle which requires org.apache.http packages. The target platform has a httpcommponents bundle which has these packages because I've seen them when I've declared in the bundle's manifest these dependencies and eclipse automatically added the bundle in the plug-in dependecies list. The problem is that I get compile errors when I `import org.apache.http`. If I explore the bundle, it only has an Activator in the package org.apache.http and has in a lib folder the jars with the packages I need. How can I access those packages? Start the activator and get the classes I need at runtime? A solution can be to manually add the org.apache.http jar to my bundle's build path. Sorry if it's a silly question...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013583/what-is-the-standard-way-to-bundle-osgi-dependent-libraries/3015072#3015072), with regards to your build problem.  Whoever built you target platform is taking the wrong approach, which is what is causing your grief.

Your target platform should in fact use the [OSGi versions of the commons libraries](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/CommonsOsgi).  Where OSGi ready versions are not available, you can get them from [Springsource bundle repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq).

If this is not a possiblity (to fix this problem), then you can simply change your classpath for your build to include the appropriate libraries.  It should already work at runtime regardless.

PS - It is not a silly question  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. In the end, I found a complete jar of the library I need to use that require the org.apache.http packages. The jar contains all the dependencies the library needs so I've included it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to ensure that your OSGi container runs the `org.apache.http` bundle when you try to start up your bundle. There are several ways to do this. You could manually copy the jar into your deploy directory, or you can use something like the [OSGi Bundle Repository (OBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi). With OBR, when you install a bundle, all of it's dependencies are also downloaded and installed.

You can host your own OBR by using the the [maven OSGi plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html). This will read the manifest file of your bundle and create a local OBR with that information. You can then use OBR from the console to install your bundle, with all it's dependencies.

Comment: It is a bit confusing because I see the packages in the dependecy list but in the import code in my class is highlighted as an error. The bundle is included as I've described above is run when my bundle is started because I've ticked it. The code runs even if it has errors but it throws a NoClassDefException when it tries to execute an line with errors (not in the import line).