# How can Maven building depend on jar files which are inside another jar file?

Tags: maven, build, osgi

We have an OSGi application:

Bundle A --> nothing but refers 10 jar files, export all the packages of those 10 jar files to satisfy the runtime calling.

Bundle B --> import packages which exported from Bundle A. Runtime OK.

But when I use Maven to build Bundle B, question appeared. Here is a piece of pom.xml of Bundle B:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycom.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.mycom.BundleA</artifactId>
  <version>${version.range}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I refer the artifactID: Bundle A, build failed. Maven cannot refer to the jar files inside the project. 
I cannot find a way to refer to the jar files which inside another project, so can anyone provide a solution to fix this dependency issues when on building-time?

Comment: Bundle A doesn't make any sense here to me, we usually directly add 10 jar dependencies to Bundle B's pom.xml.

Comment: Any other way to access jars inside A?

Comment: Simply add the dependencies to the 10 original bundles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not bundle your components this way.  It is rarely advisable to bundle one jar inside of another in OSGi, and if you do it should NOT export the packages of that jar.  If the packages need to be available to other bundles, then that jar should be an OSGi bundle.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013583/what-is-the-standard-way-to-bundle-osgi-dependent-libraries/3015072#3015072) about your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the 10 jars as dependency of Bundle A? If so Maven should be able to find the transitive dependencies when referencing Bundle A.