# adding external jar files to OSGI

Tags: osgi, knopflerfish

I have created an OSGi bundle and I want to add two external jar files to it called `mediasenseplatform.jar` and `tinyos.jar` So I added this line into my manifest file:

```
Bundle-ClassPAth:.,mediasenseplatform.jar,tinyos.jar
```

but it doesn't work and I don't see these files in my bundle jar file. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you building your bundle?

Comment: with Ant build and I use knopflerfish for deploying it

Answer (score 1):

OSGi doesn't make jar files, it is a platform for deploying and running them.  If you want to include these jars in your bunde (which is just another jar) then you have to put them in there yourself.

There are build tools like maven which can do this for you.

You may also want to take a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013583/what-is-the-standard-way-to-bundle-osgi-dependent-libraries/3015072#3015072).